# Problem when upgrading postgres from 9.5 to 11

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, upgrade, repmgr

I have a problem using PostgreSQL when tried to upgrade it from 9.5 to 11. I'm using `initdb` to make my master and when I tried to `pg_upgrade -c` there is an error like this:

> Could not load library "$libdir/repmgr_funcs": ERROR:  could not
>   access file "$libdir/repmgr_funcs": No such file or directory

I have checked `\dx`, and there is no extension installed except `plpgsql`, and I already install the new version of repmgr in Postgres 11.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Some clues: I checked `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib` and find `repmgr_funcs.so`, but it is empty. So it is safe to delete manually? I'm still replicating master to slave.

Comment: Perhaps you are connected to the wrong database.

Comment: you are right, i checked in wrong database, thanks i'll tell the result later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point in the past, repmgr had a shared library called `repmgr_funcs.so`, but not in recent versions. This can cause problems during upgrade.

The easiest solution would be to uninstall repmgr before you upgrade and then install it again on the new system.

If repmgr is installed as an extension, simply `DROP EXTENSION repmgr` on the old system. Otherwise, you will have to identify the functions and delete them individually:

```
SELECT proname, pronamespace::regnamespace
FROM pg_proc
WHERE probin LIKE '%repmgr%';
```

Please test this before you try it on your live system.